# Copy File Contiguously to Disk from OSX/Unix/Linux to FAT32 FS?

Tags: linux, mac-osx, unix, filesystems, defragmentation

So the Sysinternals guys have that cool `contig.exe` utility that allows me ensure a file is contiguous.  I need to copy overs ISO files to a FAT32 USB flash key.  Grub4DOS requires the files be continuous, but I do not have Windows access at the moment.  Is there a way to copy a file so it is contiguous on the target drive, or a tool like the aforementioned that will make an existing file contiguous.  Again, I need it on FAT32, and there lies the rub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you're copying files to empty USB-disk or to a deragmented one it's very likely files are written contiguous.

Comment: That would be nice, but I want a guarantee it will be contiguous.  I have tried that as well.

Comment: Excuse me.  I have to eat my own words.  I tried an *almost empty* disk.  After much trial and error, using different utilities like Windows defrag, `contig.exe`, and `WinContig.exe`, I had to put it on a the USB with nothing else for any utility to make a difference. (Walks away sulking in shame for not reading clearly.)